PC won't sleep while PS5 controller is plugged in
My Windows 11 PC won't go to sleep or turn off the screen automatically when while I have my Playstation 5 controller plugged in via USB. The PC will only sleep if I either manually put my PC to sleep sleep from the start menu or unplug my controller. Restarting my PC doesn't resolve the issue, even if I stay on the lock screen before logging in. Windows 11 is up to date on version 23H2.
Running powercfg -requests list no processes preventing sleep.

Looking at Device Manager, I found four devices that are added when I plug in the PS5 controller via USB. (It's possible I may have missed some). There is no Power Management tab when checking the properties of these devices.

Audio inputs and outputs > Headset Microphone (2-Wireless Controller)
Audio inputs and outputs > Speakers (2- Wireless Controller)
Human Interface Devices > HID-compliant game controller
Sound, video and game controllers > Wireless Controller

Connecting and disconnecting the controller while USBLogView is open shows three devices with the following information.

How do I get my PC go to sleep while a PS5 controller is plugged in?

This question was originally posted on Super User. For context on why it was reposted, see discussion on Meta Arqade.

I can't answer this question, but I've noticed that PlayStation controllers (since the PS4 at least) use accelerometers to identify activity. When I put down the controller while watching post game credits, the screen eventually turns dark until I pick up the controller again. I suspect the DualSense may be constantly telling your PC that it's being interacted with, preventing Windows from turning the screen off and going to standby.

@Stevoisiak Do your controllers have stick drift? Is your Windows up to date?

@Daemons I have not noticed any controller stick drift. Windows 11 is up to date on version 23H2 build 22631.4460.

What you are looking into is an original issue.
You can find the solution here, which, in short, tells you to delete your controllers drivers by following flashmau5's instructions [slightly edited for clarity]:

I finally solved it with my controller: first, download the Xbox 360 drivers from Microsoft.
Then in Device Manager, switch the controller drivers:

Then restart your PC and make sure that the Driver Version is 2.1.0.1349 (2009 drivers):


This solution is intended for Xbox 360 controllers, but the person with the PS5 controller also fixed their problem with that method.

While those links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

So the Xbox 350 drivers work for the PS5 as well? There are mentions of it working with unnamed devices, but not about the PS5 controller. Where did you find that information, and can you quote that part, too?

@Joachim there isnt exactly evidence of it working but when you go to the original issue you can see that it is closed and the questioner said thanks to Yaron2334 which leads me to believe that it worked for him but i wil look a little more into it

I installed the 360 drivers, opened Device Manager, selected HID-compliant game controller, opened properties, clicked Update Driver, hit "Browse my computer for drivers", then hit "let me pick from a list". The 360 driver did not appear as an option on the compatible list of device drivers.

i have tried to recreate it so i could test my own theorie but i had my ps5 controller plugged in my windows 10 tower and it went to sleep just fine then i tried the same for my fully updated windows 11 laptop and that also went to sleep fine so unfortunatly i couldnt recreate the issue or test my own solution

This Windows 11 forum may help. According to user Greg Carmack,

Go into Device Manager, find the Gamepad controller, open it and look for Power Management tab, remove the checkmark from Allow this device to wake computer. 
Next go into Settings-> System-> power & sleep-> Additional plan settings-> change plan settings-> change advanced power settings->  Sleep-> Allow wake timers-> disable

Note, however, that this is for a gamepad plugged in in general, not specifically a PS5 controller.

There is this Flightsim forum page where they mention,

Anyways, it appears to be fixed now after the latest update released this week.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-26-2023-kb5022360-os-build-22621-1194-preview-f6973dbe-bcc4-402a-8b9a-0541b0959403
The last line of updates listed…
" * This update addresses an issue that affects some game controllers. When the game controller is connected to the computer, the computer might not go to Sleep mode."
So, make sure Windows 11 is fully updated…

But this update was from 2023, and clearly this is still a problem on your end (unless you haven't updated Windows in a while).

As for your first potential solution: the OP mentions they have no Power Management tab. The second doesn't seem to be about the controller keeping the PC awake. And I think the third solution would be better as a comment, initially, to ask the OP if their Windows is up-to-date.

@Joachim where did they say they didn’t have a power management tab?

"There is no Power Management tab when checking the properties of these devices."

@Joachim I can't find that anywhere.

It's in the paragraph directly underneath the first image in the OPs question.

The controller has no power management tab and Windows 11 is fully up to date on version 23H2 build 22631.4460.
